# Why does the mesh have sharp edges even though it has shade smooth?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, edges

I was checking my model in viewport "Material Preview", and I noticed that the mesh has sharp edges which is odd since it has "Shade Smooth" on it. This also effects the textures that I apply to it creating a "Seam Effect" which tricks me into thinking where the shadow and lighting are placed or if the colors and patterns are incorrect.[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=oX66LLJP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/oX66LLJP/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use the *Set Shade Smooth* Node

If the tree is generated with geometry nodes, you have to run the geometry through a *[Set Shade Smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/write/set_shade_smooth.html)* node even if the you have set the object to have smooth shading.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable the *Render panel > Ambient Occlusion* option:

[image]